# 2D Game Character Animation in iPhone - How is it done?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What I mean is, do animators work on an animation in say Flash (or some other kind
of key frame animation program) and then export it to the iphone somehow?

For example, say I am an animator and I want to create a person waving for an iphone 
game. What type of external program would I use and then what libraries on the iphone
sdk would I use to load them in?

Comment: Flash CS 5 can export as a whole iPhoneOS app.

Answer (score 1):

I think it all depends on how in depth you want to get.  Making a 2D game is a broad statement.  For example, to make what you ask.  You would just make a series of PNG images for a cell based animation of the wave.  wave1.png, wave2.png, waveN.png...

Then load the PNG images in and then play them in sequence.  You can do this with UIImageView, Core Animations classes, or manually your self with UIImages and UIViews.

There a lot of great game engines you can check out too. Here is a link for an example of what is available.  [Game Engines](http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/a-look-at-8-different-iphone-game-engines-2d-and-3d/)

For the best performance, most companies/developers use OpenGL to do both 2D and 3D style games.  You can utilize a lot of tricks for the textures used in your games.

Comment: as far as displaying a bunch of png's sequentially. that probably wouldn't look as "professional" as creating a character animation in say, flash. my question was is there a way to load keyframe animation in whatever format in the iphone. but i guess i'd have to look at iphone 2d game engines and see what they have. i know opengl es isn't this high level. atleast i don't think.

Comment: The problem is that there is no native animation format for the iPhone.  You can do keyframe animations, but would need to load the images and set up the code your self.  Which is why an engine that already does this is highly recommended to safe on time.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone natively supports key frame animation with the `CAKeyframeAnimation` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most popular framework for 2D games is Cocos2D: http://cocos2d.org/